# Weird type check results comparing UITextSelectionView to UIView

Tags: inheritance, uiview, xamarin.ios

I'm iterating through a **UITextView** using its SubViews-property. I then compare the found type with **UIView** using

```
if(element.GetType() != typeof(UIView))
```

For some weird reasons some subtype of **UITextView** for example **UITextSelectionView** evaluates to true.

To my knowledge a derived class should evaluate to false - so what's happening here?

In my case I got UIContainerView which is part of UITextView and iterating over it gives me a UITextSelectionView.

[image: view (parent)]
[image: element (child)]

Both are shown with their respective types, but

`view.GetType().FullName` and `element.GetType().FullName` return for both **UIView**.

The only way to check the type "for real" seems to cast it to object:

```
> ((object)view).Class.Name "_UITextContainerView"

> ((object)element).Class.Name "UITextSelectionView"
```

Which - for me - isn't at all the same like using GetType() and typeof.

Unfortunately there is no entry in UIKit-api of xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIView/

I find it at apple dev neither: https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=UITextSelectionView

But i seemed to find a header-file here which shows that it derives as I thought : http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=UIKit.framework&header=UITextSelectionView.h

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Find subviews of UITextView which are not exactly UIView? Well in that case it works as it should, because UITextSelectionView is not an UIView. When you compare Types using GetType method and typeof operator equality evaluates to true only if those two types are exactly the same, and equality doesn't take into account the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @kyurkchyan I have a structure of UIViews which also have UIViews and so on. Some of these UIViews contain other elements such as UITextView. When I iterate starting at the top UIView I want to get only all UIViews returned, but it also gives me UITextSelectionView which is in no case a UIView and my question is - why? My example above is just an example on how to reproduce the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a short mail exchange with one of the xamarin guys and he wrote

> We try to have a 1-to-1 mapping between native and managed types, but
>   this is impossible to implement 100% because we don't know all the
>   types iOS has (since in many cases iOS uses private types). In some
>   cases Objective-C types are even generated at runtime as well.
>
> Unfortunately Xamarin.iOS can't generate managed types at runtime,
>   which means the managed wrapper types are limited to those known at
>   compile time (and they must also be documented as public API).
>
> This means that you can end up with a managed wrapper object whose
>   type does not exactly match the type of the native Objective-C object
>   (you'll only get the closest public type), which is your case.
>
> However at runtime you can see the actual type of the native object
>   (in your particular case you're seeing the output of the native
>   'description' selector (equivalent to the managed ToString method),
>   which is provided by the native object itself, and thus returns a
>   string representation of the exact runtime type).
>
> If you want to filter objects to those whose underlying Objective-C
>   type is exactly UIView, you can try something like this:

```
if (element.Class.Handle != ObjCRuntime.Class.GetHandle (typeof (UIView))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several *private* types in iOS, `UITextSelectionView` sounds like one. Private types are undocumented (by Apple), not bound by Xamarin (it would lead to app rejections) and can also differ from one iOS version to another.

What you're doing is a specific check for `UIView`, which won't consider subclasses (either public or private).

```
if(element.GetType() != typeof(UIView))
```

and that might not be what you really want (hopefully) anyway. If you want to filter out `UIView` you should consider using code like:

```
if (!(element is UIView))
```

as this will consider any subclass of `UIView` and be more robust against internal changes that might happen in future releases of iOS.

Comment: I'm using UIView - and only that object - as a container for other elements. And I want to iterate through these objects and only these (no subclasses, nothing) to do certain things. The problem now is, that I get UITextSelectionView in my resultlist although it isn't UIView.